# Something is wrong in my Langchain prompt which I am not able to catch

Tags: chatbot, prompt, openai-api, langchain, py-langchain

I have designed a simple prompt but I dont why I am getting weird output. In the first input it works fine but in following input it is simply giving me undesired output. I am still very new in AI stuff. Any help would be appreciated. I am using openAI 3.5 turbo. ALso, I tried to remove the chat_history from the prompt but still the output is weird.

```
from langchain.prompts import SystemMessagePromptTemplate, HumanMessagePromptTemplate, ChatPromptTemplate
# Define the system message template
system_template = """you are an AI assistant named aidan. your job is to recommend the best clinicians based 
on the symptoms and locations. ask the user about location preference and then recommend the clinicians based on their symptoms and preferences
        ----------------
        Context
        {context}


        Chat History
        {chat_history}
        
        QUESTION:
        {question}
        
        ANSWER:

        
        """

        # Create the chat prompt templates
messages = [
        SystemMessagePromptTemplate.from_template(system_template),
        HumanMessagePromptTemplate.from_template("{question}")
        ]
qa_prompt = ChatPromptTemplate.from_messages(messages)


chain = ConversationalRetrievalChain.from_llm(
llm = ChatOpenAI(temperature=1,model_name='gpt-4'),combine_docs_chain_kwargs={"prompt": qa_prompt}, verbose=True,
retriever=vectorstore.as_retriever())

chat_history=[]
result = chain({"question":"I have back pain." , "chat_history":chat_history,})
print(result)


// this output is good
Entering new StuffDocumentsChain chain...


> Entering new LLMChain chain...
Prompt after formatting:
System: you are an AI assistant named aidan. your job is to recommend the best clinicians based 
on the symptoms and locations. ask the user about location preference and then recommend the clinicians based on their symptoms and preferences
        ----------------
        Context
        Last name: Stebbins

Last name: pqr
Location: James Bay



Last name: def
Location: Cordova Bay


Last name: abc
Location: Vancouver



        Chat History
        
        
        QUESTION:
        I have back pain.
        
        ANSWER:

        
        
Human: I have back pain.

> Finished chain.

> Finished chain.
{'question': 'I have back pain.', 'chat_history': [], 'answer': "I'm sorry to hear that you're experiencing back pain. Could you please let me know your location preference for a clinician?"}


chat_history=[("I have concussion",result['answer'])]
result = chain({"question": """ cordova bay.
""", "chat_history":chat_history})
print(result)


// this is the weird output

Entering new LLMChain chain...
Prompt after formatting:
Given the following conversation and a follow up question, rephrase the follow up question to be a standalone question, in its original language.

Chat History:

Human: I have concussion
Assistant: I'm sorry to hear that you're experiencing back pain. Could you please let me know your location preference for a clinician?
Follow Up Input:  cordova bay.

Standalone question:

> Finished chain.


> Entering new StuffDocumentsChain chain...


> Entering new LLMChain chain...
Prompt after formatting:
System: you are an AI assistant named aidan. your job is to recommend the best clinicians based 
on the symptoms and locations. ask the user about location preference and then recommend the clinicians based on their symptoms and preferences
        ----------------
        Context
        Last name: Comfort

First name: asd
Location: Cordova Bay


Last name: fgh
Location: Cordova Bay


Last name: jkl
Location: Cordova Bay


        Chat History
        
Human: I have concussion
Assistant: I'm sorry to hear that you're experiencing back pain. Could you please let me know your location preference for a clinician?
        
        QUESTION:
        What is your location preference for a clinician?
        
        ANSWER:

        
        
Human: What is your location preference for a clinician?

> Finished chain.

> Finished chain.
{'question': ' cordova bay.\n', 'chat_history': [('I have concussion', "I'm sorry to hear that you're experiencing back pain. Could you please let me know your location preference for a clinician?")], 'answer': 'Cordova Bay'}
```